# how to exclude file name from fzf filtering after ripgrep search results?

Tags: vim, fzf, vim-fzf

I use a convenience package [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) to integrate **fzf** with **vim**. The file search works perfect and has completely replaced CtrlP plugin, but the functionality to grep files has unfortunate side-effect of fzf thinking the auto-appended filename (by ripgrep, but this would be the case with ag (silver-searcher) and regular grep as well) is part of the search string.

As a result, the best result doesn't always come to the top (or bottom in my case based on layout). Here is an example:
[image]
The result that appears last in this case should actually be first because it's the only result that matches by content (as intended by Rg) rather than file name. This problem is especially frustrating on large repos, where irrelevant results could litter your entire search space.

I should also clarify that the problem occurs because I invoke `:Rg` from a shortcut, so the filtering is done by fzf, not rg (which just dumps everything to fzf).

This problem occurs in default `:Rg` implementation bundled with **fzf.vim** as well as my attempt to roll my own:

```
command! -bang -nargs=* Rg
  \ call fzf#vim#grep(
  \   'rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case '.shellescape(<q-args>), 1,
  \   <bang>0 ? fzf#vim#with_preview('up:60%')
  \           : fzf#vim#with_preview('right:50%:hidden', '?'),
  \   <bang>0)
```

I couldn't figure out how to remedy this issue. Can someone help?

Answer (score 14):

Something that worked out for me is redefining `Rg` as follows:

```
command! -bang -nargs=* Rg call fzf#vim#grep("rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case ".shellescape(<q-args>), 1, {'options': '--delimiter : --nth 4..'}, <bang>0)
```

I wish I came up with this myself, but honestly, after facing the same issue as you have, I was lucky to get [this](https://dev.to/iggredible/how-to-search-faster-in-vim-with-fzf-vim-36ko) blog post in my search results.  If you are like me and get confused how and why this works, [this](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/346) issue thread in fzf github repo describes the anatomy of the command above (and offers the same solution to the problem).

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much for sharing! This has actually been bugging me for years 

Comment: For those who use the preview window, just put the `options` inside the `fzf#vim#with_preview` call, like `fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': '--delimiter : --nth 4..'})`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your own `ripgrep` shortcut as called inside vim to not return the filename when searching, so that you can use your search results down the line.

`man rg`:

> ```
>    -I, --no-filename
>        Never print the file path with the matched lines. This is the default
>        when ripgrep is explicitly instructed to search one file or stdin.
>        This flag overrides --with-filename.
> ```